# node-inspector command not found

Tags: node-inspector

I've tried to install and run `node-inspector` with a bunch of different commands and still unable to run it:

```
Jordans-MacBook-Pro:angular-express-blog jordanbaucke$ node-inspector
-bash: node-inspector: command not found
```

Here is my configuration

```
Jordans-MacBook-Pro:angular-express-blog jordanbaucke$ node -v
v0.10.15
Jordans-MacBook-Pro:angular-express-blog jordanbaucke$ npm -v
1.3.5
```

I installed using:

```
Jordans-MacBook-Pro:angular-express-blog jordanbaucke$ sudo npm install -g node-inspector
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-inspector
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-inspector
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor

> ws@0.4.27 install /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/node-inspector -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/bin/inspector.js
node-inspector@0.3.2 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/node-inspector
├── async@0.2.9
├── glob@3.2.6 (inherits@2.0.0, minimatch@0.2.12)
├── express@3.2.6 (methods@0.0.1, fresh@0.1.0, range-parser@0.0.4, cookie-signature@1.0.1, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, cookie@0.1.0, debug@0.7.2, commander@0.6.1, mkdirp@0.3.4, send@0.1.0, connect@2.7.11)
└── socket.io@0.9.16 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)
```

Still no change.

Node runs fine, and `node --debug app.js` works.

I just can't start the inspector.

`OS X 10.8.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the key to your problem:

```
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/node-inspector -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/bin/inspector.js
```

Make sure that `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` is in your `PATH` environment variable.

Alternatively, you can run node-inspector using the full path

```
$ /usr/local/share/npm/bin/node-inspector
```

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs when the node-inspector is not installed globally.

To install globally use *npm install -g node-inspector*

If you don't have root permission try the following:
*sudo npm install -g node-inspector*

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on a Windows server. The node-inspector module was installed globally. However, missing from the system path was the directory to globally installed node modules--in my case

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm;

Updating the path (as described in @Prasad's post) resolved my issue running node-debug on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this-**

Open cmd prompt

npm config get prefix

you done this -

C:>npm config get prefix
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm;

Solved !